# Support of Probability Measure is Compact

Tags: measure-theory

Let $P$ be a probability on the Borel $\sigma$ - field of $\mathbb{R}$ such that every continuous real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ is integrable with respect to $P$. Show that support of $P$ is compact (support of $P$ is the smallest closed subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with $P(C)$ = $1$).
My idea was to assume the contrary and produce a function which is not integrable,
but I am unable to solve it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $A_{n}=[-n,n],\ B_{n}=A_{n}\backslash A_{n-1}$. If the support is not compact, then there exists a subsequence such that $c_{k}:=P(B_{n_{k}})>0$. If $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(B_{n_{k}})\subseteq [1/c_{k},\infty]$ then $f$ is not integrable.