# Prove that the support of $\mu$ is compact.

Tags: measure-theory, compactness, borel-measures

> Let $\mu$ be a measure on the Borel $\sigma$-field of $\Bbb R$ such that $\mu (\Bbb R) = 1.$ Recall that the support of $\mu$ is the largest closed set $C$ such that for all open sets $U$ with $U \cap C \neq \varnothing$ we have $\mu (U) \gt 0.$  Assume that every continuous real-valued function is integrable with respect to $\mu.$ Prove that the support of $\mu$ is compact.

What I observe is that I need only to prove that $C$ is bounded because by Heine-Borel theorem then we are through.

How do I prove boundedness of $C\ $? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't $\mathbb{R}$ be the support here?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129688/a-sufficient-condition-for-a-probability-measure-to-have-compact-support/129690

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263707/support-of-probability-measure-is-compact?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will flesh out the terse proof to which @user203940 pointed.

If the support of $\mu$ is not compact, then it is not bounded. **This means that there is a countably infinite number of non-overlapping intervals that have positive $\mu$-measures.**

Suppose that the support of $\mu$ is not compact. Let  $\{(a_n,b_n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a collection of non-overlapping intervals that have positive $\mu$-measures. We assume without loss of generality that $0 < a_n < b_n < a_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $f$ be a positive-valued and continuous real-valued function that is *constant on each of these intervals*. Let

- $c_n = f(a_n)$
- $\epsilon_n = \mu((a_n,b_n))$.

Then
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)d\mu(x) ~\geq~ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}c_n\epsilon_n.
\end{equation}
We have not put too many restrictions on $f$. As $n$ grows, construct $f$ by interpolation between intervals so that $f(x) = \epsilon_n^{-1}$ for $x\in(a_n,b_n)$. Then $c_n = \epsilon_n^{-1}$.

We now have
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)d\mu(x) ~\geq~ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}c_n\epsilon_n = \infty.
\end{equation}

Comment: Very nice argument. Many many thanks to you sir.